# How do you find what regulations have been made pursuant to a particular enabling legislation in the U.K.?

Tags: united-kingdom, legal-research, regulations

How do you find what regulations or other statutory instruments have been made pursuant to a particular enabling legislation in the U.K.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [statutory instrument search site](https://statutoryinstruments.parliament.uk) allows you to do an advanced search for all statutory instruments made under a particular enabling act.

For example, [these are all the statutory instruments made or in process under the Equality Act 2010](https://statutoryinstruments.parliament.uk/?SearchTerm=&House=&ActOfParliamentId=SmQ2LS8f&LayingBodyId=&Procedure=&ParliamentaryProcess=&RecommendedForProcedureChange=&ConcernsRaisedByCommittee=&MotionToStop=&DebateScheduled=&ShowAdvanced=true).

Some statutory instruments are not properly indexed in that database, so you would also want to do an advanced search for the title of the enabling act at https://www.legislation.gov.uk/search. E.g. [here is a search for all secondary legislation that contains the phrase "protection from eviction act"](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/secondary?text=%22protection%20from%20eviction%20act%22).

The statutory instrument search site might be underinclusive, while the legislation.gov.uk/search results are usually overinclusive.

Comment: This is much better for searching for SIs than legislation.gov.uk!